# Compare new input with previous stored input

Tags: python, list

So, let's say I have a list; a random number between 1 and 100

```
randomNumber = random.randint(1,100)
list = []
```

And I take input from a user, in this case a number, and append it to the list above.

```
guess = int(input('Please make a guess'))

list.append(guess)
```

My question is: How do I check if the range between the new input from user to the `randomNumber`, is shorter than the distance between the previous guess to the `randomNumber`?

I'm working on a Guessing Game, if the context helps

Comment: Use subtraction..??

Comment: can you explain with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
randomNumber = random.randint(1,100)
list = []

def guess():
    guess = int(input('Please make a guess'))

    list.append(guess)
    comparingTo = len(list)-2 if len(list)-2 > 0 else 0

    if randomNumber - guess < randomNumber - list[comparingTo]: # if the guessed number is lower than the latest array value...
        return True
```

for this line,
`list = []`
I recommend you to change this variable name because its overriding built-in function `list()`

Comment: Just figured it out, to check list[-2], I added an if condition: if len(list)==2:

Comment: @SebastianCarazo, i add additional line. But if you would, just comment it with "#".

Answer (score 0):

Well, the previous input is list[-1]. Thus, just conpare list[-1] with randomNumber and guess with randomNumber by substraction.

Comment: The thing is I have to compare the new guess to attempts[-2], cause I want to check if abs(guess-randomNumber)<abs(attemtps[-2]-randomNumber), and when I do that, I get an error